# Strange behaviour of Prestashop database

Tags: phpmyadmin, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I imported a database from an online Prestashop website and I can´t edit some tables.

This is how it looks like the ps_category_lang
[image]

And this is how it looks like the same table on a fresh install
[image]

There are a lot of tables with this issue and I don´t know how to repair it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Set `$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique']` to `true` in your `config.inc.php` settings file for phpMyAdmin.

This option controls the display of actions in rows for tables without a unique key.

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RowActionLinksWithoutUnique

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the unique / primary key on the `id_category`.

[image]

Regards